# Google Search Console: How to remove url which is under the AMP

Tags: google-search-console

We have added rel="amphtml" in some of the pages mistakenly so that URL is going into AMP section in google search console. But I don't want to used that url as a AMP so I have removed that rel="amphtml" from all that URL but now that all URL still showing into AMP page list.

So how can I remove from this AMP list?

Any idea please share.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this meta tag in pages and google will take time to remove search listing :

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
```

Comment: Then you can wait a couple of hours it will be removed automatically.

Comment: I have removed those things 2 days ago but still not updated. I have also set the 301 redirec url  from amp to without amp

Comment: Then I need an example so I will help you

Comment: Now, when I check this URL in URL inspection then it will be showing a message that "Not an AMP page" but this url still available in AMP section

Comment: Please install this extension and check you local : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-validator/nmoffdblmcmgeicmolmhobpoocbbmknc?hl=en

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209694/discussion-between-tushar-kumawat-and-camit1dk).